# Php framework with easy code and performance?

Tags: php, frameworks, web

I am new to php development and want to choose a single php framework which is **easy to learn** with followings in mind:-

1. fast development
2. less code
3. customization
4. performance of created project.

Comment: ALL Frameworks are built for fast development, less code, extreme customization and performance. It boils down to which is more suitable for your requirements and which one you find faster to learn. I suggest you check them all out and see where which one you find comfortable.

Comment: Here is a good list of alternatives: http://alternativeto.net/software/codeigniter/

Answer (score 3):

This probably isn't the appropriate forum to ask this type of question, but I would recommend you to take a look at [CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com) anyway.
It is known for being easy to learn (it has a nice to follow documentation), don't leave you overwhelmed with a lot of features you don't know if you are going to need it, and manages to be [considerably fast](http://leftblank.nl/php-framework-benchmark-zend-codeigniter-cakephp-481.html).

Comment: Yea this question will be trouble because it does welcome a lot of opinion on a gray area.  That being said please give Yii framework consideration, personal favorite of mine.

Comment: And what about YII is it difficult for a new programmer ?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it for a beginner, just because it's component based. In the end, you should just try it and see what you can do with.

Answer (score 1):

[WordPress](http://wordpress.org) is a content management system not necessarily a framework. Since you are new to PHP I would direct you away from frameworks towards a CMS like WordPress. While WordPress will get you off your feet developing fast you will be exposed to a code base that is dead brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

This question never seems to end, blogs, forums, seminars, trainings etc etc.

Major frameworks that i know of

- Zend - you will never run out of career options
- Codeignitor - very easy to learn as compared to other frameworks and isn't probably as advanced as other frameworks.
- Cakephp - amazing, enchanted (auto magic), rapid code generation. Completely takes monotonity out of the picture. very fast since version 2 but **Bad documentation**
- Yii - not as much magical as cake, but definitely with Yii began a new generation of php frameworks. Extremely fast

I have been using Cakephp for 3 years, i love it but since as you are beginning i would say go with **"Yii"**. Cake is very hard to learn without supervision. Many of my team members over the years when left without supervision have struggled to converge on projects.

Whereas for Yii, i have seen

Comment: And what about YII is it difficult for a new programmer ?

Comment: Yii definately has good documentation. But if you are planning for unsupervised learning, it will be bit difficult but it also depends on your learning curve ;)